# Optimal performance

Tags: ssd, adobe-premiere, scratch, cinema4d

Below is a list of my storage and HDD config.

```
Samsung 850 EVO 250GB (SSD)
Samsung 970 EVO Plus 500GB (SSD)
Western Digital WD4004FZWX 4TB (SATA III)
Western Digital WD4004FZWX 4TB (SATA III)
```

I am currently running the OS (WIN10) and all apps including Adobe CC (Premiere Pro/AE/PS/Illustrator), Cinema 4D etc. on the Samsung 850 EVO and using the two WD 4TB SATA as file storage and scratch/cache disk for the likes of Premiere Pro, After Effects and Photoshop.

I have also just today added the Samsung 970 EVO Plus.

So, my question is should I run the OS and all apps on the 970 EVO Plus and use the 850 EVO as the scratch/cache disk? Then use the two WD 4TB drives for storage only?

Or would I be best to simply use the 970 EVO Plus as a new scratch disk? Or would you do something completely different with these options?

TIA,
ozmo

Comment: Using the Samsung Data Migration software you can clone the 850 Evo on the 970 Evo Plus, thus being able to take advantage of the best read and write speed

Comment: Thanks, @spike_66. Would It then be best practice to set the 850 Evo as a dedicated scratch/cache disk?

Comment: Yes, the 850 Evo as scratch disk would be perfect.